# Gradle how to use custom buildFile with projectBuilder

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to pass a custom buildFile to `ProjectBuilder`:

```
    given:
    File tempDir = File.createTempDir()
    File buildFile = new File(tempDir,'build.gradle')
    buildFile << """
        plugins {
            id 'com.myplugin.gradle'
        }
    """

    when:
    Project project = new ProjectBuilder()
            .builder()
            .withProjectDir(tempDir)
            .build()

    then:
    project.getProjectDir() ==  tempDir
    project.tasks.getByName("oneOfMyTasks") != null
```

However, that buildFile is not getting applied. 
When I apply it directly, it does work:

```
    when:
    def project = new ProjectBuilder().build()
    project.plugins.apply('com.myplugin.gradle')

    then:
    project.tasks.getByName("oneOfMyTasks") != null
```

How do I provide a custom buildFile to ProjectBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

The `ProjectBuilder` implementation doesn't need a build script file. Instead you have to apply plugin directly to the `Project` instance returned by the `build()` method.